# R how to combine data from a for loop in one txt file

Tags: r, for-loop, text-files

I have one loop

```
for (chr in paste('chr',c(seq(1,22),'X','Y'),sep='')){
.
.
write.table(exp,file="list.txt",col.names =FALSE,row.names=TRUE,sep="\t")
 }
```

right now the loop will give me only one txt with the data from the last loop (chromosome Y)

What i want is one txt file with the data from all the chromosomes/ from all the loops. Not 24 different txt (one per chromosome)

Thank you

Best regards
Anna

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `append=FALSE`?  Also, your code will be much better (and faster) if you first create a `data.frame` with your data and then use a single `write.table` to save your data to disk.

Comment: that piece of the code is a just a piece of big code.....so i just need a way to make a txt file with the data from all the repetitions of the loops...is the append wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you are not yet recognizing is that 'append' is set to FALSE by default and that you need to explicitly change it to TRUE if you want to record each 'exp'-object (which by the way is an unfortunate name for a data object because it's shared by a common math function). If you set append=TRUE and if the "exp"-object is a full record of one chromosome at each time the write.csv is called  (hopefully with an 'chr'-identifier column so you can keep track of where the data came from), then you should succeed.